# What do the parameters at the top of an FCIDUMP file mean?

Tags: software, ab-initio-calculations, molpro, fcidump, full-configuration-interaction

A while ago I wrote a simple program that takes in an `FCIDUMP` file (generated by `MOLRPO`) and can determine matrix elements (or construct the whole FCI matrix), with the help of this forum in [this thread](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/how-to-calculate-fci-matrix-elements-from-an-fcidump-file).

However, I didn't use any of the values at the top of the file, except for `NORB` and `NELEC` (which in the string representation were just half the length of the string and the number of ones). Presumably these serve to reduce the size of the matrix somehow ([maybe something with group theory](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/how-is-group-theory-used-to-deduce-which-of-these-integrals-are-equal-to-0)), or have something to do with the irrep of the determinants. **What do these parameters mean?**

Perhaps it would also be helpful to work with an example, like the minimal STO-3G basis H2 (separation 1.4 bohr), if I use my program (which is hopefully correct...) I get an FCI matrix:

```
[[-1.83100004  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.18125791]
 [ 0.         -1.24609329  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -1.06483537  0.18125791  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.18125791 -1.06483537  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.         -1.24609329  0.        ]
 [ 0.18125791  0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.25370925]]
```

However, I know from Szabo and Ostlund (e.g. using pg 162) that this is reduced to

```
[[-1.8310000369984170       0.18125779940066075]
 [0.18125779940066075      -0.25371106084836703]]
```

How do I get here given the following?

```
NORB=  2,NELEC=  2,MS2= 0,
ORBSYM=1,5,
ISYM=1,
OCC=  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
CLOSED=  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
```

And do the parameters give any extra information besides what is in the matrix?

Comment: +1 but "minimal basis set" could mean STO-3G or STO-2G or STO-6G, MINAO, etc. so perhaps you can be more specific (or give the page number for the Szabo and Ostlund book) if you want someone to be able to reproduce those numbers.

Comment: Good point, I updated the post. I used STO-3G, I'm not sure about the page number but I think pg 162 should help, and I used `MOLPRO` to generate the `FCIDUMP` file (the PySCF function in the previous question I found just by searching the web).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MS2` is related to the spin. Specifically, it is the number of unpaired electrons. Your molecule is a singlet, which is why it says `0`.

`ORBSYM` is the list of symmetries for each orbital. In this case $\ce{H2}$ is in $D_{\infty h}$ but almost all electronic structure codes do not support non-Abelian groups, so instead we would almost always use $D_{2h}$. The `FCIDUMP` format was invented by Peter Knowles, and the writing and reading of `FCIDUMP` files would have been implemented in MOLPRO long before other software, so assuming this `FCIDUMP` was written by MOLPRO, you can figure out what the `1` and `5` mean from the $D_{2h}$ table [here (Table 2)](https://www.molpro.net/info/current/doc/manual/node36.html). This tells us that the first molecular orbital is of type $A_g$ and the second is of type $B_{1u}$. That makes sense because in your minimal basis set with only 2 spatial orbitals, you have $\sigma$ and $\sigma^*$ bonding and anti-bonding orbitals. You mentioned PySCF in the other question, and unfortunately [they have a different convention](https://sunqm.github.io/pyscf/symm.html) for labeling the irreps of $D_{2h}$, in which $A_g=0$ and $B_{1u}=5$, which is not what you have in your `FCIDUMP`, perhaps because you didn't use PySCF to print the `FCIDUMP`, or because the PySCF documentation has an error. My open source ["Quantum Chemistry Cheat Sheet"](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/QC_CheatSheet/blob/master/symmetry) will help you translate between the languages of many of the most popular electronic structure programs, and here I'll just copy and paste from there the relevant information for $D_{2h}$ since you're dealing with $\ce{H2}$:

| $D_{2h}$ | irrep | MOLPRO | MRCC | CFOUR | PySCF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $s$ | $A_g$ | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| $p_z$ | $B_{1u}$ | 5 | 6 | 5 | 5 |
| $p_y$ | $B_{2u}$ | 2 | 7 | 2 | 6 |
| $p_x$ | $B_{3u}$ | 3 | 8 | 3 | 7 |
| $d_{xy}$ | $B_{1g}$ | 4 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| $d_{xz}$ | $B_{2g}$ | 6 | 3 | 7 | 2 |
| $d_{yz}$ | $B_{3g}$ | 7 | 4 | 6 | 3 |
| $d_z^2$ | $A_g$ | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| $d_{x^2-y^2}$ | $A_g$ | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| $f_{xyz}$ | $A_u$ | 8 | 5 | 8 | 4 |

By the way if you don't like how the $d_{x^2 - y^2}$ orbital turns out in the table, you might consider supporting [my feature request to fix that bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357525/391772) .

`ISYM` is the overall symmetry of the molecule. $A_g \times B_{1u} = A_g$, which was labeled as `1` in the program that you used to print that `FCIDUMP`.

`OCC` are the occupied orbitals for each irrep of the point group, which in this case is $D_{2h}$ so there's 8 entries there. Only an $A_g$ orbital is occupied, so the entries for all other irreps is `0`, and the $A_g$ irrep has only one occupied orbital, which is the $\sigma$ bonding orbital, so we have a `1` there. **This means the anti-bonding $\sigma^*$ orbital does not have any electrons in it.**

`CLOSED` are the closed orbitals, with the same convention as `OCC`. Since there's 2 electrons in the one occupied orbital, we have a "closed" orbital. It would be open if it didn't have 2 electrons in it.

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late. Does the bold text in your answer by `OCC` imply the reduced size somehow or do you reduce the CI matrix some other way? I guess I am confused how to use this information meaningfully.

Comment: @tmph The bold text says that the bonding orbital has 2 electrons and the anti-bonding orbital has 0 electrons, which makes sense for a system with 2 electrons and 2 orbitals, that's in the ground electronic state. You can use the spin (`MS2`) and spatial symmetry (`ISYM`) to reduce the number of determinants, and hence the number of CI coefficients, but that would have to be left for a different question, or more likely, two separate questions because I foresee more people being able to answer the question about spin and far fewer people being able to (or willing to) answer about spatial sym.